# State change detection with a colour sensor

Tags: arduino-mega, programming, midi

I have added static variables to this code and instead of getting repeated notes whilst dwelling on green, I get a single note instead. This is what I wanted. However, my loop isn't allowing for a new note to be fired either when the sensor returns to a green colour. I'm afraid I'm not getting the hang of this!

```
  /*
  // TCS230 color recognition sensor
  // Sensor connection pins to Arduino are shown in comments

  Color Sensor      Arduino
  -----------      --------
  VCC               5V
  GND               GND
  s0                8
  s1                9
  s2                12
  s3                11
  OUT               10
  OE                GND
*/
#include <MIDI.h>

const int s0 = 8;
const int s1 = 9;
const int s2 = 12;
const int s3 = 11;
const int out = 10;

// LED pins connected to Arduino
int redLed = 5;
int greenLed = 6;
int blueLed = 7;
// Variables
int red = 0;
int green = 0;
int blue = 0;
int indeks = 0;
const int rgbr = 7;
const int rgbg = 6;
const int rgbb = 5;

MIDI_CREATE_DEFAULT_INSTANCE();

void setup()
{
  MIDI.begin();                      // Launch MIDI and listen to channel 4

  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(s0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rgbr, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rgbg, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rgbb, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(s1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(s2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(s3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(out, INPUT);
  pinMode(redLed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenLed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(blueLed, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(s0, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(s1, HIGH);
}

void loop()
{
  color();

  int tmpr = (((20 - red) - 10) * 30); //int tmpr=(((20-red)-10)*30);
  int tmpg = (((20 - green) - 10) * 30); //int tmpg=(((20-green)-10)*30);
  int tmpb = (((20 - blue) - 10) * 30); //  int tmpb=(((20-blue)-10)*30);

  if (tmpr < 0)
    tmpr = 0;

  if (tmpg < 0)
    tmpg = 0;

  if (tmpb < 0)
    tmpb = 0;

  if (tmpg > tmpb && tmpg > tmpr)
  { tmpb = 0;
    tmpr = 0;
  }
  analogWrite(rgbr, tmpr );
  analogWrite(rgbg, tmpg );
  analogWrite(rgbb, tmpb );

  static uint8_t noteOn;

  if (tmpg > 149 && tmpg < 151) {
    static uint8_t noteOn = 0;
    if (!noteOn) {
      noteOn = true;
      MIDI.sendNoteOn(79, 127, 1);    // Send a Note (pitch 79, velo 127 on channel 1)
      MIDI.sendControlChange(64, 127, 1);

    }
  }
  else {
    static uint8_t noteOn = 1;
    if (noteOn) {
      noteOn = false;
      MIDI.sendNoteOff(79, 0, 1);     // Stop the note
      MIDI.sendControlChange(64, 0, 1);

    }
  }
}

void color()
{
  digitalWrite(s2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(s3, LOW);
  //count OUT, pRed, RED


  red = pulseIn(out, digitalRead(out) == HIGH ? LOW : HIGH);

  digitalWrite(s3, HIGH);
  //count OUT, pBLUE, BLUE
  blue = pulseIn(out, digitalRead(out) == HIGH ? LOW : HIGH);
  digitalWrite(s2, HIGH);
  //count OUT, pGreen, GREEN
  green = pulseIn(out, digitalRead(out) == HIGH ? LOW : HIGH);

}
```

Comment: please include your attempts, so that we can see in which area you need help

Comment: Hello, I've replaced my code with new suggestions but still to no avail...

Comment: please format your code correctly ..... highlight all of the code text and click `{}` button

Comment: you are keeping track of only one note (any note)

Comment: problem is, that I don't know how to keep track of the note that I have

Comment: us an array (use boolean values, they are true/false) .... http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/   .... when you play a note, set the corresponding array element .... when you stop the note, clear the corresponding array element

Comment: i re-read your question .... the thing that is adding to the difficulty is that you are trying to do multiple things during the development of your code ..... best thing to do is to start another sketch that is the same as this one with one major difference, there is no midi code .... replace the midi code with a subroutine that turns on an LED when the sensor detects green color and turns off the LED when the sensor no longer detects green color ............. when you have a solidly working program, then add the code for midi

Comment: That's the thing, I want the midi note or as you suggest, an LED, to light only the once whilst on green and not continually. When sensor values change and green is encountered again then the allocated note will play (once). I will strip back the code but I really thought the issue was simple, though unobtainable to me so far...

Comment: you have not defined the program's desired behavior correctly ..... you determined that the note should play when the sensor is `over a green area` ..... that is not what should happen ..... the note should play when the sensor `enters a green area` .....  those two behaviors are completely different ..... that means that you have to keep track of the background color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the MIDI library for Arduino does not keep track of which notes are on or off, you will have to do that yourself.

Add a `static` variable called `noteOn` that will hold a `0` or a `1`, keeping track of whether you have a note turned on or not.

Then, when your `loop()` determines that it should turn on a note, it first checks if a note is already on. If the note is not already on (`!noteOn`), then send note on command, and set `noteOn=true` (same as `noteOn=1`) so that next time around, you won't send the note on command again.

```
void loop()
{
  static uint8_t noteOn;

  [...]

  if (tmpg > 149 && tmpg < 151) {
    if (!noteOn) {
      noteOn = true;
      MIDI.sendNoteOn(79, 127, 1);    // Send a Note (pitch 79, velo 127 on channel 1)
      MIDI.sendControlChange(64, 127, 1);
    }
  } else {
    if (noteOn) {
      noteOn = false;
      MIDI.sendNoteOff(79, 0, 1);     // Stop the note
      MIDI.sendControlChange(64, 0, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks jose can u c! Can you tell me what this means ( [...]) Also, what do you mean by keeping track of which notes are on or off? I have tried you code but unfortunately i still have the same problem of repeated notes...

Comment: [...] is just where I omitted some of your code that was unrelated to the relevant additions to answer the question.

Comment: I edited the answer to have a more explanation of what I mean by keeping track of which notes are on or off.

Comment: I thought I should attach my code with your additional code but i don't understand how or where I should post that!

Comment: Possibly should I edit my original post and replace it with the new code?

Comment: Yes, edit the question, add your revised attempt.

Comment: One more thing -- the logical *AND* operator is `&&`, not `&`.

Comment: I have changed the static variable noteOn to equal a '0' in the first if and then in the 'else if' I've changed it to a '1'. this gives me a first note played once but only once. I thought 'noteOn' was already keeping track but it isn't?